# Create list of abbreviations?

Tags: acronyms

I am trying to create list of abbreviations. I've seen some examples but I would like it too look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [glossaries](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries?lang=en) package. Linked [here](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/#glossaries) are a few examples on how to use it.

Here is a MWE on how to get something like what you want, taken and slightly modified from the example site linked, to remove page numbers and change the title of the acronyms section to Abbreviations.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nopostdot,toc,acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\loadglsentries[acronym]{myglossaries}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample}

First use:

\gls{fema}
\gls{cbow}

\printglossary[title={Abbreviations},type=acronym,style=long]

\end{document}
```

The line : `\loadglsentries[acronym]{myglossaries}` merely loads a file (myglossaries.tex) containing your glossary entries formatted like this:

```
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{cbow}{CBOW}{Continuous Bag-Of-Words}
\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{fema}{FEMA}{Feature Embeddings for domain Adaptation}
```

You need to provide this .tex file yourself, so you can make your own glossaries file with your own file and entries.

Here is an example of the output:

[image]

Comment: thank for your answer. How to I override the default behaviour of this package such that ONLY the abbreviations appear in main text, even in First Use?

Comment: @arilwan I know this is old, but please don't do that. Why would you want to?